# Angular Material md-select

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-material

For some reason when I use the md-select the floating label doesn't work and the label shows way below the md select.

I used Angular Material site as a reference: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/select

And here is my code:

```
   <md-input-container>
                    <label>Display</label>
                    <md-select ng-model="controller.x"  multiple>
                        <md-option ng-repeat="status in controller.x">
                          <md-checkbox>{{x.display}}</md-checkbox>
                  </md-option>
                    </md-select>
```

Comment: I think your {{x}} can't be good because you seem to use controllerAs syntax so in this case if x is define in your controller you need to call {{ctrl.x}}

Comment: Thanks I had changed my variables just to not give to much info. But that's not what is causing the label to not float. I will try to upload a picture

Comment: I use a class on my md-container md-block and it does work fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some test i have find two thing:

- **first** your  `<md-checkbox class ="blue">{{status.containerStatus}}</md-checkbox>` it's weird but it's maybe normal in your context I can't be sure without more information
- **Second** list of checkbox seems to have some bug with old version off angular material I try with 1.1.1 and it seems to be ok (but not with 0.9.3 for example). You can find my example here in [codepen](http://codepen.io/quentChap/pen/NbGLBw)

Comment: 1. Thanks for your response. The blue is a custom class I and to change the pink color of the check box. 2.That might be true I will check my version and see if I can update it

Comment: It looks like I have version 0.10.0.

Comment: have you try to upgrade the version ?

Comment: I tried running npm install angular but it doesn't seem to be upgrading

Comment: You can see [here](https://github.com/angular/material/releases) there is an 1.1.1 version so I think this is a configuration problem on your side. Can you show me your line about angular material in your package.json ? thanks

Comment: {
  "name": "angular-material",
  "version": "0.10.0",
  "main": "index",
  "format": "cjs",
  "registry": "github",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.3.15 || >1.4.0-beta.0",
    "angular-animate": "^1.3.15 || >1.4.0-beta.0",
    "angular-aria": "^1.3.15 || >1.4.0-beta.0"
  },

Comment: ok can you try to install again with `npm install angular-material@1.1.1 --save`

Comment: so our project is kind of weird i have a nodes modules folder and a vendor folder. the update goes to the node_modules folder but not the vendor. and the application is reading from the vendor folder

Comment: what is the command that you use to run your angular ? Usually vendor folder is use to contain all imported code but often this folder isn't use during the developement period. Normaly this folder was update by grunt or gulp.

Comment: Hi @qchap. do you know if it's possible to have md-float with md-chips?